# CSS width: auto acting strange

Tags: html, css

I'm setting the width of a div to 'auto'. When i refresh the page the divs width is extremely wide and goes way off my screen. I can't go and set an explicit width for this div since I have to cater for diff screen sizes.

Any idea why this would happen?

Edit > My code as requested:

CSS:

```
.table{
max-width: 100%;
height: 250px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
overflow: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
margin-top: 20px;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table" id="MedeLogSearchTable"></div>
```

Comment: Post the CSS to your table containers as well.

Answer (score 2):

`width:auto` is the default value for width of a div, what you want to do is add a percentage value instead.

Comment: Hi Andres. I tried width: 100% ... but the problem still remains.

Comment: Would it maybe work when I set an inline style rather than referencing a CSS file?

Comment: @DeanGrobler It should work either way, referencing the div in css is more semantic though. Try `max-width:100%;`, if nothing happens then please post your code, we're walking in the dark here.

Answer (score 1):

If the width of the div goes out of screen with `width: auto` (which is the default value), it probably means that the **parent** of the div is wider than the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the parent tag like a parent div as `position:relative` or `position:absolute` and try to specify your last div as position relative. Also test the page with other browsers than Explorer. For example Firefox, Chrome, or Safari. Debug the code if possible with the Firebug extension which is present in the plugin market of Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Try

**Simple structure example :**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftmenu">LEFT</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="table" id="MedeLogSearchTable">
            <table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And CSS :**

```
#container {
    max-width: 1600px;/* a max-width may be desirable to keep this layout
        from getting too wide on a large monitor. */
    min-width: 600px;/* a min-width may be desirable to keep this layout
        from getting too narrow.  */
    background: #FFF;
}

#leftmenu {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
#content {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}

.table {
        width: 100% ;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        overflow: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-top: 20px;   
}
```